# How to use primary and foreign key constraints?

Tags: python, unqlite

I have started exploring unqlite database, but the issue is that I cannot find any solution for primary and foreign constrain. For primary key every record by default it creates _id key, but still I am not able to find any thing foreign key concept. If anyone could help me with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnQLite is a key/value database engine, it doesn't support relations with foreign keys like relational database (e.g. MySQL). It also doesn't have indices. You can look up a value by key for O(1). If you need any filtering like `WHERE` queries in SQL, you need to iterate over [all the keys](https://unqlite-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#cursors) or [filter a collection](https://unqlite-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#Collection.filter) with a Python function which is also iterating over all the collection.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have tried to explore and Just wanted to be sure.